# How do I run LAMPP on Microcore Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, xampp

I'm trying to install LAMPP 1.7.7 on a Microcore Linux, but after extracting the files with `tar`:

```
tar xvzf /root/Desktop/xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C /opt
```

I can't run LAMPP, with the command

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

nor

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

and I receive the message "no such file or directory"

When I do the same steps on Ubuntu it works perfectly, how do I make it work on Microcore Linux?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to run a bash script without bash installed, follow instructions http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/install.html to install bash and possibly procps and other dependencies are required as well